# Как остановить выполнение метода?

Tags: c#

Метод поиска файлов:

```
private List<string> GetFilesList(string path, string pattern)
{
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (pattern.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName)))
        {
            fileList.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Метод проверки папки:

```
static long GetDirSize(string path)
        {
            long size = 0;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (string file in files)
                size += (new FileInfo(file)).Length;
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
                size += GetDirSize(dir);
            return size;
        }
```

Теперь делаю проверку:

```
if (GetDirSize(TxtPath) < 1000000)
{
   // Если папка превышает размер: остановить метод GetFilesList(path,pattern);
}
else
// Если не превышает продолжить метод пока папка не будет превышать заданный размер.
```

Беда в том что я не могу всё реализовать вмести ( с использованием цикла `while(true)`, или на таймере.

P.S: Суть сделать проверку,и остановить вызываемый метод после превышения размера папки.

P.P.S: Поставлю вопрос немного в другой форме:
При вызове метода `GetFilesList(path,pattern);` - Файлы копируются у меня в папку (все файлы), это занимает давольно долгое время, и вес! Поэтому нужно сделать проверку на размер папки, и остановить выполнение функции метода).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите запустить проверку (`GetDirSize`) и получение перечня файлов (`GetFilesList`) параллельно? И если не отработата проверка, то прекращать процесс получение перечня файлов.

Comment: @Vlad, Да именно так!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того какие папки вы обрабатываете, если "папки вообще", то это вполне штатная ситуация, в которой папки будут превышать нужный вам размер, тогда примерно так:

```
private int GetFilesList(string path, string pattern, out List<string> fileList)
{
    int result = 1;
    fileList = new List<string>();
    if (GetDirSize(path) < 1000000)
    {            
        result = 0;
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(
                    path
                 , "*.*"
                 , SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
             if (pattern.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName)))
             {
                 fileList.Add(fileName);
             }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

И соответственно обрабатывать коды возвращаемые функцией.

Если же это вполне конкретные папки, которые "обязаны" иметь определенный размер, тогда в наличие исключительная ситуация, и работать с ней лучше через исключения.

```
public class DirSiztException : Exception
    {
        public DirSiztException() { }
        public DirSiztException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public DirSiztException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
        protected DirSiztException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
    }

private List<string> GetFilesList(string path, string pattern)
{
    if (GetDirSize(path) > 1000000) throw DirSizeExeption("Directory {0} size is too mach", path);
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (pattern.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName)))
        {
            fileList.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: в Вашем примере в 1 посте, в `return result` вызывает ошибку:                                                                                                                                                                                                                `Ошибка 1 До передачи управления из текущего метода параметру, помеченному ключевым словом out, "fileList" должно быть присвоено значение`

Comment: @ArteS Подправил, перенесите присвоение из ифа.

Comment: А при вызове  `GetFilesList(path,pattern,что здесь требуется?);`

Comment: @ArteS, там требуется какой нибудь список, для возврата значений. раньше вы его вызывали: `List<string> files = GetFileList(..)`, а теперь так; `List<string> files; if (GetFileList(... , files) == 0) { какие то действия foreach (var f is files) {} //например }`

Comment: Во-первых, `SearchOption.AllDirectories` - зло - при исключении будут проблемы, а во-вторых, у тебя уже полный массив в памяти.

Comment: @Qwertiy, А что тогда использовать за место `SearchOption.AllDirectories`? Может Вы предложите код для разъяснения?

Comment: @ArteS, рекурсивный обход.

Answer (score 7):

Эти методы надо объединить и возвращать `IEnumerable<Tuple<String, long>>`, где в первом элементе лежит имя файла, а во втором суммарный размер. Соответственно, проверяя размер, можно узнать, что нужный лимит достигнут и на этом закончить.

Comment: Если не сложно приведите пример)

Answer (score 3):

Я предложу такой вариант.

В метод `GetFilesList` добавляем параметр `CancellationToken t`. Внутри цикла `foreach` вызываем `t.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.

После этого пытаемся собрать все в кучу

```
static async Task GetFiles()
{
    // перечень файлов
    List<string> filesList = null;
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    // запускаем задачу по отмене операции. Если размер директории слишком большой - вызываем `Cancel` у `CancellationTokenSource`.
    var cancellationTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (GetDirSize("") > 1000000)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    });

    try
    {
        // запускаем операцию и ожидаем ее результатов
        filesList = await Task.Run(() => GetFilesList("", "", tokenSource.Token));
        // если задача по высчитыванию необходимости завершения еще не завершилась, то дожидаемся ее
        await cancellationTask;

        // бросаем OperationCanceledException, если запрос на отмену был произведен
        // этот метод бросит исключение в том случае, если cancellationTask отменила выполнения, но длилась дольше, чем задача получения перечня файлов
        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // операция отменена
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // что-то пошло не так
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArteS Причем здесь `Linq`?

Comment: А. Ну для `.Net 2.0`, конечно, не прокатит такое решение.

Comment: Перешёл на пример с Linq, можно уточнить пару деталей?!  Как вызывать и завершать?! ( или же он сам завершается при достижения большого кол-во файлов в папке ( и при проверке останавливает если вес достиг нужного размера ) ?))

Comment: @ArteS, вызывать - await GetFiles(). Завершится метод самостоятельно: либо с отменой, если будет превышено количество файлов в папке, либо успешно.

Comment: запутался немного, в строке: `GetFilesList("", "", tokenSource.Token));` пустые скобки это для (путь,формат файлов,token)); ?

Comment: @ArteS, ну да, это путь, формат и токен. Путь и формат можно передать в метод GetFiles через параметры или задать константой (в зависимости от ваших нужд). Я задал пустые строки, чтобы была понятна сигнатура. Это ваш метод с небольшими доработками.

Comment: а проверку `GetDirSize` нужно в обоих случаях писать? Я про метод `GetFilesList`.

Comment: @ArteS, в каких "обоих"? Ее же там вообще нет.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте return
к примеру

```
return null;
```

или

```
return new List<string>();
```

или

```
return fileList;
```

Comment: довольно плохое решение, так как оно неинформативно: в папке нет файлов, или произошла ошибка, а если ошибка, то какая. Такую программу очень сложно будет отлаживать, да и логгирование настраивать тоже не весело.

Comment: если произойдет ошибка, монжно обернуть в try catch. или обложить проверками и выкидывать каждый раз exception. Как я понимаю в данном случае, автор не хотел выбрасывать exception, а лишь не выполнять дальнейщий код метода.